# Do double-enchantments not work in 1.0?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In 1.9pre, you could enchant items multiple times, but in MC 1.0.0, nothing even comes up when I put an enchanted item on an enchantment table. Has this been removed? Is it a bug? I am in SMP, if that's important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Items could never be enchanted multiple times.

It was (and still is!), however, possible to get multiple enchantments at once (as long as you spend enough levels).

Comment: Perhaps you could make it more clear how to get multiple enchantments at once?

Comment: @Arkive The only way to get multiple enchatments is to spend enough levels at once. There are a couple of random factors that play into this, so there's not much more I can suggest other than, "always enchant with all the levels you have".